# Python Error Handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was trying to convert the list to a set, with the following code:

```
set1=set(list1)
```

the code was running fine, but all on a sudden started to give the following error,

```
set1=set(list1)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

please let me know how may I resolve.

And sometimes some good running program gives error all on a sudden with no parameter changed, how may I debug it?

Comment: What are the contents of `list1`?

Comment: I'm a little upset you got so many downvotes for your question, the error message *can* be confusing if you don't immediately realize that a list containing *another* list is the cause of the error. Could everyone give new users a bit of a break, please?

Comment: Sorry to get meta here, Martjin, but given the biography and SO history of the poster we've not got a newbie here, but someone who should know how to read an faq and the suggestions made in prior posts but who seems to have not. (I didn't downvote, though, mostly because I don't). This question is dreadfully incomplete.

Comment: @msw: Okay, you have a point here; I only saw the 1 point reputation and jumped to a conclusion. I *can* somewhat see how the error message is confusing to newbies though, and there is a terrible tendency to just downvote "for dumbness" on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Your list contains another list:

```
>>> set([['contained list'], 1, 2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Sets can only contain items that are [*hashable*](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable); any standard type that cannot be mutated is hashable, but a `list` is not (it can be mutated). By contrast, a `tuple` is not mutable and can be stored in a `set`.

Bugs happen, even in code that has been running fine for a while. Debug it with print statements, or better still, by using a debugger like the [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html).

If your bug only appears intermittently, use a `try`/`except` block to catch the error, then print out information or use a debugger to figure out what is going on:

```
try:
    set1=set(list1)
except TypeError:
    print 'list1 not hashable? contents: %r' % list1
    # optionally: import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    raise
```

Comment: My list does not contain another list. That is the worry Sir.

Comment: @SUBHABRATA: the error message seems to indicate otherwise. Without more of your code we cannot help you more though. Use an exception handler to determine what the contents are, answer updated.

Comment: Using try_except is a good one. I am taking a list, manipulating it,taking another blank list, appending to the blank list, and now converting this into set, easy code for --I have my way to resolve but that is bit raw I was thinking bit of expert help. pdb i'll check. Thanks and Regards, Subhabrata.

Answer (score 4):

Your error suggests that your list contains a list. Lists are mutable and thus can't be hashed for use in a set or a dictionary. One work-around is to convert your list into a tuple using `tuple(some_list)`, but if they're heavily nested, it becomes more complex.